# How to reference SCSS sibling?

Tags: css, sass

Assuming that I have the following HTML:

```
<div class="navigation__item">
  <span class="navigation__item__icon"></span>
</div>
```

I want to apply some rules to an icon, when hovering an item, which can be described with the following CSS:

```
.navigation__item__icon {
  color: black;
}

.navigation__item:hover .navigation__item__icon {
  color: white;
}
```

I can achieve this using the following SCSS:

```
.navigation__item {
  &:hover {
    .navigation__item__icon { <-- here
      color: white;
    }
  }

  &__icon {
    color: black;
  }
}
```

Here, is there any way to avoid writing `navigation__item`? Something like "parent rule \ element".
I like Sass for logical structure so that if I want to rename the whole `navigation` block with elements, I can simply change `navigation` class name in the root, and everything is renamed. This case breaks this advantage.

**Update:** Actually, I have found a way to do this without using {} braces. `&` can be repeated more than once:

```
.navigation__item {
  &:hover &__icon {
    color: white;
  }

  &__icon {
    color: black;
  }
}
```

It is great, but it doesn't make much sense if I have many rules and rules for `&:hover` itself. The question is still open - is this possible to access sibling element definition from within the {} block.

Comment: It's also not a sibling...it's a child.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Stylus there is a [Partial reference](http://stylus-lang.com/docs/selectors.html#partial-reference) but I don't know anything similar in SASS. One solution could be using a variable for the parent selector:

```
.navigation__item {
  $selector: &;
  &:hover {
    #{$selector}__icon {
      color: white;
    }
  }

  &__icon {
    color: black;
  }
}
```

Is usefull is you change `navigation__item` class for another.

**EDIT:** I had used a wrong example, it's OK now.

Comment: "Partial reference" is actually what I was looking for. I hope, there will be something like this in SASS in future :) Thank you for this approach with variable. Probably, I will use this one.